# Pass variable from accordion to JS function

Tags: javascript, html, function, dynamic, accordion

I have an accordion with 10 section. I also have some JS that has some code to get images from flickr. I want to be able to click the accordion and populate a div within the accordion section that got clicked with an image pertaining to the accordion section.
Example

### SUVs

### Cars

Trucks

when the user clicks the cars accordion section, I want to populate a div within the cars section accordion with cars. I already have the accordion and image working. I need to add the piece to make the on click of the accordion section add the appropriate image.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you have some `HTML` like this one:

```
<div id="SUVs" class="accordionElement"></div>
<div id="Cars" class="accordionElement"></div>
<div id="Trucks" class="accordionElement"></div>
```

And you need the `Javascript` necessary to append certain images to each of them. First you have to change your `HTML` to this (for example):

```
<div id="SUVs" class="accordionElement" onclick="appendImage(this);"></div>
<div id="Cars" class="accordionElement" onclick="appendImage(this);"></div>
<div id="Trucks" class="accordionElement" onclick="appendImage(this);"></div>
```

Then a `Javascript` code as follows:

```
function appendImage(element){
    $(element).append('<img src="pathFromImage/' + $(element).attr('id') + '.jpg" />');
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on $(this).append('<img src="images/' + imageIdentifier + '.jpg" />');

Comment: That was my bad, I've edited the answer. Thanks a lot.